# Is it appropriate not to complete a re-assigned task so that your colleague who did not do the work cannot claim credit in his or her resume

Tags: resume, management, colleagues, stress

This colleague that I mention in my scenario ([How to handle being assigned a colleague's work when the colleague does not complete it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18018/handle-colleague-who-dont-do-work-and-end-up-you-doing-your-colleague-work)) have decided to leave the company because he/she have manage to find greener grass out there.

So, would it be right that I not complete the task that was re-assigned by my boss and persuade my boss to agree with my action. (so that the colleague will not use the work that is performed by you and list inside his / her resume.)

Comment: Why do you keep insisting? There's a revenge factor in your questions - what do you need to be right about? With that underlying sentiment this does not seem like a proper 'Workplace' question...

Comment: Why do you even care about this?

Comment: As [Ross Drew](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/18054/12796) answered, not just it's inappropriate, but it can be seen as a huge red flag for your boss. You're worrying more about not something that *could* benefit your ex-colleague than the task that needs to be done by your company. Suppose that this tasks involves finishing a feature for a product that a big client requested. Just because this hapenned, does not mean the feature can be simply cancelled. If you like your job, I highly suggest thinking about it too.

Comment: Well personally, I'd fire you if you did that. It is highly unprofessional. You have been assigned the work, just do it.

Comment: How on earth would you not finishing the task prevent him from saying whatever he wants to in his resume?

Comment: If I was your boss, and you decided not to complete tasks I assigned you because you were afraid your ex-colleague would take credit for them, you'd be following him out the door - although I would be generous enough to express my fervent hope that it did not hit you on the ass on your way out.

Comment: Do the work, get the credit. You can't get applause for doing nothing.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see why someone falsely taking credit for your work is any reason for you not to do the work you are paid for.  What difference would it make to you or your company if they did take credit?  What's to stop him/her taking credit for anything, even things he had nothing to do with? Does it stop you taking credit later? Also, how would you be benefiting you or your company by refusing to do the work?

Playing political games (including [handling colleagues when you don't need to](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18018/handle-colleague-who-dont-do-work-and-end-up-you-doing-your-colleague-work), [going over your bosses head because you don't like how they handle people](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18053/is-it-appropriate-not-to-complete-a-re-assigned-task-so-that-your-colleague-who/18054#18054) and rebelling against work you are given) for rewards based on pride is not going to work in your favor, you're going to be in trouble because you are not doing what you are being paid to do.

So no, I don't think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Your boss couldn't settle with your colleague's poor work and decided to reassign the task to you. That implies that the task is important to your boss - maybe even to the entire company. refusing to complete it would be sacrificing the interest of the employer for the sake of revenge on the colleague - something I doubt your boss would like.

No - it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

A new employer has no guarantee that anything in a resume is 100% true, embellished, or a downright lie. It may appear unjust that your colleague appears to have got a new job based on falsely claiming credit, but it's up to the new company to verify facts and if they don't, more fool them. Refusing to do your company's work because you're peeved about the situation is petulant - you should be glad that you're rid of the colleague, and you have a chance to prove how much more valuable you are than he was.

And if he doesn't deliver the goods at this new company he will in due course be found out. It's not a trick you can pull repeatedly.